# How many terms of the series do we need to add to find the sum to the indicated accuracy

Tags: calculus

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{5n^4}$ ($|error| < 0.00005)$. I have no idea how to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** the error of an alternating series $ \sum a_n $ can be bounded as

$$ |R_n| \leq a_{n+1} .$$

Comment: I need more than just that please.

Comment: As Mhenni Benghorbal told, just write that the absolute value of the last term to be considered (say for n=m) is smaller than the right hand side term. Does this give you an idea of what to write ?

Comment: So it would be something like this correct? 1/5n^(4) < 0.00005? @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: @mike. You are right. Now, what is n ?

Answer (score 1):

We have that the error must be $\left | R_p \right |< 5\cdot 10^{-5}$

We also have that the error is of less value than the (n+1)th term after the last term you've taken for your sum, so we have:
$$\left | R_p \right |< C_{p+1}=\frac{1}{5\cdot \left ( n+1 \right )^{4}}<5\cdot 10^{-5}$$